# Unity. Return generic type in a InjectionFactory

Tags: c#, unity-container

In a WebAPI project, I have two different implementations of the same generic interface:

```
public interface Interface<T> {}

public class Class1<T> : Interface<T> {} where T : class
public class Class2<T> : Interface<T> {} where T : class
```

I need to decide runtime, depending some parameters in the request, which implementation to use. So I confirgured the unity container like this:

```
....
container.RegisterType(typeof(Interface<>),
            new InjectionFactory(
                c =>
                    ToggleInjectionFactory.Get(container,     
                                               typeof(Class1<>),
                                               typeof(Class2<>),
                                               HttpContext.Current.Request)
            ));
...

// Factory
public class ToggleInjectionFactory
{
...
    public static object Get(IUnityContainer container, Type typeTo1, Type typeTo2, HttpRequest request)
    {
        if (Toggle.IsOn(request))
        {
            return container.Resolve(typeTo1);
        }
        return container.Resolve(typeTo2);
    }
}
```

But I'm having an error because `typeTo1` and `typeTo2` contain generic parameters. Error message:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Class1`1[T]", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: ArgumentException - Type Class1`1[T] contains generic parameters
```

Is there any way to implement `container.Resolve(typeTo1)` so I can return a closed type instance? I don't want to rewrite the register statement for each posible type `<T>` that I have.

Comment: I dont think it is possible what you are trying to achieve...You need to register all the possible type.

Comment: @Viru, you're right that out of the box Unity won't do what the OP wants but with a little coding you can add the requested functionality to the container.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few approaches that could be used to get the outcome you want but the simpler ones suffer from not scaling well as the logic gets more complicated and the number of classes grows.  I'm thinking here of Registration by Convention, conditional registrations, and named registrations.

Unity lets you register open generics and have them resolved to closed generics automatically.  However, the posted approach using an `InjectionFactory` doesn't work because the `InjectionFactory` does not have the resolving `BuildContext` that Unity uses to create the closed generic type.

One solution to achieve what you want is to use a Unity Container Extension because the Container Extension will have the build context available and let you determine the correct type to build.  In this case a simple type mapping can be done during the TypeMapping stage of object resolution.

```
public class ToggleExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    private Toggle toggle;

    public ToggleExtension(Toggle toggle)
    {
        this.toggle = toggle;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Context.Strategies.Add(new ToggleBuildUpStrategy(this.toggle),
            UnityBuildStage.TypeMapping);
    }
}

public class ToggleBuildUpStrategy : BuilderStrategy
{
    private Toggle toggle;
    public ToggleBuildUpStrategy(Toggle toggle)
    {
        this.toggle = toggle;
    }

    public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        // If we have an Interface<> then do some type mapping to the applicable concrete class
        // Note that I'm using Toggle here because something similar was used in the question
        if (context.BuildKey.Type.IsGenericType && 
            context.BuildKey.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Interface<>))
        {
            Type target = null;

            // Luckily HttpContext.Current.Request request context is available here
            // For other non-static contexts might have to work out how to inject into the extension
            if (this.toggle.IsOn(HttpContext.Current.Request))
            {
                target = typeof(Class1<>);
            }
            else
            {
                target = typeof(Class2<>);
            }
            // Get generic args
            Type[] argTypes = context.BuildKey.Type.GetGenericArguments();

            // Replace build key type Interface<> => Class1<> or Class2<>
            // So that the correct type is resolved
            context.BuildKey = new NamedTypeBuildKey(target.MakeGenericType(argTypes), 
                context.BuildKey.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Toggle implementation I used -- it's not quite the same as in the question but being non-static makes testing easier:

```
public class Toggle
{
    private bool isToggleOn;

    public void SetToggleOn()
    {
        isToggleOn = true;
    }

    public void SetToggleOff()
    {
        isToggleOn = false;
    }

    public bool IsOn(HttpRequest request)
    {
        // Implement more complicated toggle logic
        return isToggleOn;
    }
}
```

And finally some tests to make sure the correct types are being resolved:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
Toggle toggle = new Toggle();
toggle.SetToggleOn();

container.AddExtension(new ToggleExtension(toggle));

Interface<X> x = container.Resolve<Interface<X>>();
Debug.Assert(x.GetType() == typeof(Class1<X>));

toggle.SetToggleOff();

x = container.Resolve<Interface<X>>();
Debug.Assert(x.GetType() == typeof(Class2<X>));
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks Randy!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are over complicating the solution. Instead a simpler approach would be not pushing this into the IoC container. The reason is that DI is to maintain logic independent of the dependencies and their logic.

In this case, you have a switch which determines your dependency stack and you are then just pushing that into the resolution creating dependencies between your container and the actual logic. This could cause problems as it is just pushing around your resolution issues, not actually solving it. In this case, the logic of determining the switch may very well be suited to have the object resolution (it is what that logic does most likely... What is the "Toggle")
It seems that if you have the switch in a logic piece it should be the owner of determining the first step of resolution. Granted, you would still use some IoC for the final interface to concrete class resolution, but don't push the switch logic to the IoC.

In other words, can you have another layer of interfacing that the IoC resolves on and then the calling resolver uses a type switch for the base interface?

```
IBaseInterface resolvedObject = Toggle.IsOn(request) ? di.Get<IToggledInterface>() : di.Get<INotToggledInterface>();
```

Note: The interfaces being resolved use IBaseInterface for final exposure. They both impliment the interface, however they themselves may add nothing to the signiture other than a "Type" definition that allows the IoC to resolve on.

Comment: I see your point, but the problem is that the dependency is used in a lot of controllers that are already done and that I can't change. 

There's no business logic in the toggle, it's kind of a feature toggle. I'm replacing some classes and I need to be able to decide run time and per request which implementation to use. That's why I need to be able to configure the toggle in the container.

I need to test the new implementation in a controlled group of requests in production before removing the current classes.

Comment: I see. Well your approach is sort of right, but the error tells you exactly what is going wrong. Your types being passed in nave Generic signitures and the resolver has no way to know what it should resolve on for that generic. It's not clear from your code what that generic is or is used for. I am guessing some details of the problem are still missing, but the solution is to get rid of the generic because as is, it does not seem necessary. If it is necessary you need to explain its purpose as well. It would be like declaring a List<T> myList; Generics are resolved at compile time, not runtime

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking heavy inspiration from Randy's answer, but I disagree that you have to jump through hoops with an Unity extension. An `InjectionFactory` works fine, if you're a bit careful.

The code below just resolves from any open type `I<>` to a corresponding type `C<>`.
It does not do the toggling part, but that's just an `if` statement away.

For the impatient: [runnable fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WdLFOJ)

Usage:

```
interface I<T> { }

class C<T> : I<T> { }

...

var ioc = new UnityContainer();
ioc.RegisterType(
    typeof(I<>), //can't use ioc.RegisterType<I<>>(...), C# doesn't support that
    // generic type mapping defined here
    // the first type parameter must match what's above, in this case typeof(I<>)
    new OpenGenericTypeFactory(typeof(I<>), typeof(C<>)) 
);

var c = ioc.Resolve<I<double>>();
Console.WriteLine(c.GetType());
```

This prints:

```
C`1[System.Double]
```

The implementation of the factory:

```
class OpenGenericTypeFactory : Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionFactory {
    public OpenGenericTypeFactory(Type from, Type to)
        : base((container, type, _) => Create(container, from, to, type))
    {
    }
    
    private static object Create(IUnityContainer container, Type fromType, Type toType, Type requestedType)
    {
        if (!requestedType.IsGenericType || requestedType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != fromType)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Injection factory for {fromType}: got type {requestedType} instead.");
        }

        Type[] argTypes = requestedType.GetGenericArguments();

        var closedGenericTarget = toType.MakeGenericType(argTypes);
        try
        {
            return container.Resolve(closedGenericTarget);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to resolve type {closedGenericTarget} for requested type {requestedType}");
        }
    }
}
```